# How to design a database to store OHLC time-series of different resolutions?

Tags: sql, time-series, google-bigquery, database-schema

What is the best way to store OHLC data for various stocks if I might have different frequencies for the stocks? For example, I might have:

```
* OHLC for 5-minute bars for APPL
* OHLC for 1-minute bars for APPL
* OHLC for 5-minute bars for IBM
```

I was thinking about storing everything in the same table and just adding a column that specifies the resolution so it might look like this:

```
symbol, date,       time, resolution, open,  high,   low,   close
AAPL,   2017-06-19, 9:30, 5 min,      99.12, 102.52, 94.22, 98.34   
AAPL,   2017-06-19, 9:30, 1 min,      99.12, 100.11, 99.01, 100.34
IBM,    2017-06-19, 9:30, 5 min,      40.15, 45.78,  39.18, 44.22
```

Does that seem fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does look fine. Just as another possibility for you, you could also store each new resolution as a separate `STRUCT` (record) inside of an `ARRAY` (repeated field), like so:

```
WITH data AS(
  select 'APPL' as symbol, ARRAY<STRUCT<date string, time string, resolution INT64, open FLOAT64, high FLOAT64, low FLOAT64, close FLOAT64>> [STRUCT('2017-06-19' as date, '9:30' as time, 5 as resolution, 99.12 as open, 102.52 as high, 94.22 as low, 98.32 as close), STRUCT('2017-06-19' as date, '9:30' as time, 1 as resolution, 99.12 as open, 100.11 as high, 99.01 as low, 100.34 as close)] stock union all
  select 'IBM' as symbol, ARRAY<STRUCT<date string, time string, resolution INT64, open FLOAT64, high FLOAT64, low FLOAT64, close FLOAT64>> [STRUCT('2017-06-19' as date, '9:30' as time, 5 as resolution, 40.15 as open, 45.78 as high, 39.18 as low, 44.22 as close)]
)

SELECT * FROM data
```

Which results in:

[image]

Notice that as you store new values for resolution it adds another row into the ARRAY defined for each stock.

You can also aggregate the ARRAYS on the date level like so:

```
WITH data AS(
  select 'APPL' as symbol, STRUCT<date string, time string, hit ARRAY<STRUCT<resolution INT64, open FLOAT64, high FLOAT64, low FLOAT64, close FLOAT64>>> ('2017-06-19', '9:30', [STRUCT(1 as resolution, 99.12 as open, 102.52 as high, 94.22 as low, 98.32 as close), STRUCT(5 as resolution, 99.12 as open, 100.11 as high, 99.01 as low, 100.34 as close)]) stock union all
  select 'IBM' as symbol, STRUCT<date string, time string, hit ARRAY<STRUCT<resolution INT64, open FLOAT64, high FLOAT64, low FLOAT64, close FLOAT64>>> ('2017-06-19', '9:30', [STRUCT(1 as resolution, 40.15 as open, 45.78 as high, 39.18 as low, 44.22 as close)])
)
SELECT * FROM data
```

That results in:

[image]

This type of schema might give you some advantages depending on how much data you are processing such as a cheaper and more effective storage as well as faster queries (you might find sometimes that the difference between a query returning `Resources Exceeded` error and it working is the wise usage of [STRUCTS and ARRAYS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#arrays_and_structs)).